# std::size() not available in C++ 17

Tags: c++, c++17

I am confused of std::size. I did something people said, making sure `#include <iterator>` and using C++17 as cpp standard. But the compiler still say "size is not a member of std".
Here is an example:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::cout<<std::size(array);
```

I am using VS code, in which I take GCC as my compiler. Following is my `c_cpp_properties`. Perhaps something wrong in my configuration?

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "D:\\software\\mingw32\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My `g++ --version` : "g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0".

When I use `g++ -std=c++17` in the terminal to compile, it works. But directly using VS code "run build task" doesn't work.

My `tasks.json`:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\software\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                // "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "D:\\software\\mingw32\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },  //why there are two blocks? I modified tasks.json it works well.
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\software\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "D:\\software\\mingw32\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your compiler doesn't support C++17.

Comment: Or you didn't use the option to enable C++17 support.

Comment: How do you compile? Did you set the compiler Flag ? `-std=c++17`

Comment: [std::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) most certainly *is* part of C++17. I use it in my own code both with clang 7, GCC 9 and MSVC 2019.

Comment: What does `g++ --version` output for you?

Comment: It's 8.1.0.    `g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`

Comment: What does your `tasks.json` file look like? See e.g. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_build-helloworldcpp

Comment: Thanks, I see a commented *out* `"-std=c++17"` in `"args"` in one of the tasks. Have you tried to remove the `//` and add that option to both the tasks?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried add this, but it doesn't work for "run build task". But if I implement this in command line, `-std=c++17` works fine. I saw somebody in 2018 said C++ extension haven't support all c++17 features. Maybe still not?

Comment: OH, I didn't see `-std=c++17` during compiling

Comment: Have you added it to the "second" task too (the one with `"isDefault: true"`)? I usually run a `makefile`, though.

Comment: Thanks, I restarted a project, adding `-std=c++17` in `tasks.json`, and it works fine. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::size()` is available [starting from C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Try enabling `-std=c++17` for your compiler (your GCC version might not support C++17 by default. To enable C++17 support, add the command-line parameter `-std=c++17` to your g++ command line).

Also, for C++17 support in GCC, you can refer to [C++17 Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17).

In addition, please double check that the source files contain `#include <iterator>` (I know you said you already checked this, but double checking is always good), either directly, or indirectly by #include'ing any of the following headers:

```
<array>
<deque>
<forward_list>
<list>
<map>
<regex>
<set>
<string>
<string_view>
<unordered_map>
<unordered_set>
<vector>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am sure not including any other header files, because this is just simply one file program.